# code only in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

i have the final version of visual studio 2010
i wanna use CODE ONLY in entity framework 
i wanna know what is ctp 
what is ctp in entity framework
please help me

Comment: You wanna get the CTP here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=af18e652-9ea7-478b-8b41-8424b94e3f58&displaylang=en

Comment: hello thanks for your answer
but i have the final version of VS 2010 and net framework 4. you mean i should download the CTP 3?

Comment: hi thanks for your answer
but i have the final release of VS2010 and net framework 4. you mean i should download the CTP3 ? the code only is not supported in final verison of .net?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx